# Error about making an area in ASP.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

When I wanna make an area in my project at ASP.net core 2.2 this error occurs...

In visual studio 2019 when I wanna make an "area"at ASP.net core mvc this error occurs: Unable to load the service index for source http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.jason.   How can I fix this???

Comment: `.jason` should be `.json`, surely. Did you mess with the nuget config at all?

Comment: Yes that should be json and how can I fix this?? I think the problem is nuget config doesn't load

Comment: You can change it in the Nuget configuration options in visual studio, or by editing the Nuget.config file manually. There are lots of instructions about this online already if you don't know where to find it